# How to make image in a list view place on then right side?

Tags: android, listview

[Image of My Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly2V6.jpg)

[image]

I'm having a list view with images. but the image is showing on the left side how can i place that image on the right side and change its size...

My XML code is..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/album1" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Itemname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
```

My Mainactivity.java code is...

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String[] itemname ={
            "Safari",
            "Camera",
            "Global",
            "FireFox",
            "UC Browser",
            "Android Folder",
            "VLC Player",
            "Cold War"
        };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, R.layout.mylist,
                R.id.Itemname,itemname));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:layout_gravity="right"` for imageview and `android:layout_gravity="left"` for textview.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Itemname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/accessdenied" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yea it will not work as your orientation is horizontal.... with horizontal orientation, only vertical alignments work and similarly for vertical orientation, only horizontal alignments work...

Answer (score 1):

just swap the views as follow

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Itemname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="asdas"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/case_card" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i need the imageview at the right end. Now as per the code the image is next to the textview

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/icon"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  android:src="@drawable/album1" />
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/Itemname"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="20sp" 
  android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or you can swap your views in the LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/Itemname"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp" 
android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:src="@drawable/album1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Error:(6) No resource identifier found for attribute 'alignParentEnd' in package 'android'

Comment: my bad its layout_alignParentEnd and layout_alignParentStart

Comment: sorry man, silly mistake on my part :) no android studio access currently... anyway, if you choose the relativelayout approach, make sure that your adapter also changes your layout if you access it using LinearLayout